Why doesn't Coq notation defined by other notation working well?
Here is my Coq code.
I expected Check x ∪ y. shows x ∪ y but ∪ {x, y}.
Why? Or is there another idea to define notation?
My Coq version is 8.16.1.
Section Test.
  Variable set:Type.
  Variable In : set -> set -> Prop.
  Notation "x ∈ y" := (In y x) (at level 50).

  Structure class φ := {
    class_base :> set;
    class_row : forall x, x ∈ class_base <-> φ x;
  }.

  Axiom build_union : forall F, class (fun x => exists Y, x ∈ Y /\ Y ∈ F).
  Notation "∪ F" := (build_union F) (at level 50).

  Axiom build_non_ordered_pair_set : forall x y, class (fun w => w = x \/ w = y).
  Notation "{ x , y }" := (build_non_ordered_pair_set x y) (at level 45).

  Notation "x ∪ y" := (∪ {x, y}) (at level 50).

  Variable F x y:set.

  Check ∪ F.
  (* ∪ F                                                          *)
  (*      : class (fun x : set => exists Y : set, x ∈ Y /\ Y ∈ F) *)

  Check {x, y}.
  (* {x, y}                                       *)
  (*      : class (fun w : set => w = x \/ w = y) *)

  Check x ∪ y.
  (* ∪ {x, y}   <- Why is not x ∪ y ?                                    *)
  (*      : class (fun x0 : set => exists Y : set, x0 ∈ Y /\ Y ∈ {x, y}) *)
End Test.

I have known the below code is work well.
  Axiom build_two_union : forall x y, class (fun z => exists Y, z ∈ Y /\ Y ∈ {x, y}).
  Notation "x ∪ y" := (build_two_union x y) (at level 2).
  Check x ∪ y.


It looks like the elaborator inserts a coercion and then the printer does not recognise the expression associated to the notation.
When you write x u y, the parser replaces the notation with build_union (build_non_ordered_pair_set x y), which is ill-typed since build_non_ordered_pair_set x y has type class _ whereas build_union expects a set. So the elaborator inserts class_base that you declared as coercion, turning the term into build_union (class_base _ (build_non_ordered_pair_set x y)). Now, the printer recognises the notations for u F and {x, y}, but the class_base prevents it from recognising x u y.
If this is right, defining your notation like so should work:
Notation "x ∪ y" := (build_union (class_base _ (build_non_ordered_pair_set x y))).
